# "SQLite warning (28): double-quoted string literal" in VisualStudio C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Im using SQLite database `System.Data.SQLite` (NuGet package version 1.0.115.5). Every time i execute a database query, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE parent_task=1073 LIMIT 1;
```

got 2 warnings in debug log:

```
SQLite warning (28): double-quoted string literal: "L"
SQLite warning (28): double-quoted string literal: "P"
```

But im not even using double quotes in my query. Is it a problem with sqlite or im missing something?
Or maybe there is a way to disable sqlite warnings, because it generates a lot of garbage in my log.

### Edit

c# code:

```
public static DataTable AsDataTable(this SelectWhere_Extends_SelectFrom q)
{
   AASqlite sqlite = new();
   SQLiteDataAdapter da = new($@"SELECT {q.column_list} FROM {q.table_name} WHERE {q.where} {q.limit};", sqlite.connection);
   Debug.WriteLine(da.SelectCommand.CommandText);

   DataTable ds = new();
   da.Fill(ds);

   return ds;
}


// AASQLite class
...
public AASqlite() => connection = new($"Data Source={G.DB_PATH}");
```

Debugger data:
[image]

#### Edit 2

Are you convinced now?
[image]

#### Edit 3

Tested it with simple static query. Even this throw warnings.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new($"Data Source={G.DB_PATH}");
connection.Open();
new SQLiteCommand("select * from tasks", connection).ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Can you show the actual relevant code?

Comment: Now can you show the verbatim value of the adapter select command text at runtime?

Comment: This is the one i already posted `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE parent_task=1073 LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I'm not convinced those warnings are coming from that query but at this point I'm all out of guesses. On another note, I'm not sure how you are building those query properties but it looks like there is potential for sql injection.

Comment: I don't experience this with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Maybe it has something to do with the implementation or sqlite compile options of whatever AASqlite is.

Comment: Which version of .NET you are using? Mine is 4.8

Comment: I'm using .NET 6. I figured you were on at least .NET 5 because of the new() syntax.